# Can WCF service transmit type (client doesn't know this type) information?

Tags: wcf, service

I'm working on a simple plug-in framework. WCF client need to create an instance of 'ISubject' and then send back to service side. The 'ISubject' can be extended by the user. The only thing client knows at runtime is ID of a subclass of 'ISubject'.

Firstly, client need to get type information of a specific subclass of 'ISubject'. Secondly, client using reflection to enumerate all members to create a custom property editor so that each member can be asigned with proper value. Lastly, client create an instance of that subclass and send back to service.

The problem is how does client get the type information through WCF communication?

I don't want client to load that assembly where the subclass (of 'ISubject') exists.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't sound too promising. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: No, you can't do this - WCF is about **serialized** (XML) messages - you can't send unknown object types across the wire and re-assemble them on the client without knowing about them... WCF is **NOT** a "object-remoting" kind of system (like DCOM or CORBA) - by design

Comment: Spender, I define a interface ISubject which can be extended by plug-in framework user. The framework (run on server side) can load the subclass of ISubject at runtime from third-party assembly. The client needs to create an instance of extended subclass and send back to server side. I use WCF for the communication between server and client. So, the problem is how client get the type information to create an instance of sub-class (I use reflection so the type info is needed). Note: I don't want to client load the third-party assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to be aware that there is no magic way that WCF will provide any type information to your client in the scenario you have descibed. If you are going to do it, you will have to provide a mechanism yourself.

Next, understand that WCF does not really pass objects from server to client or vice versa. All it passes are XML infosets. Often, the XML infoset passed includes a serialized representation of some object which existed on the sender's side; in this case, if the client knows about that type (i.e. can load the type's metadata from its assembly), it can deserialize the XML to instantiate an identical object on the client side. If the client doesn't have the type metadata, it can't: this is the normal case with WCF unless data contract types are in assemblies shared by both server and client implementations (generally not a good idea).

The way WCF is normally used (for example if the client is implemented using a "Service Reference" in Visual Studio), what happens is that the service publishes WSDL metadata describing its operations and the XML schemas for the operation parameters and return values, and from these a set of types is generated for use in the client implementation. These are NOT the same .NET types as the data contract types used by the service implementation, but they are "equivalent" in the sense that they can be serialized to the same XML data passed over the network. Normally this type generation is done at design time in Visual Studio.

In order to do what you are trying to do, which is essentially to do this type generation at runtime, you will need some mechanism by which the client can get sufficient knowledge of the structure of the XML representing the various types of object implementing ISubject so that it can understand the XML received from the service and generate the appropriate XML the service is expecting back (either working with the XML directly, or deserializing/serializing it in some fashion). If you really, really want to do this, possible ways might be:

- some out-of-band mechanism whereby the client is preconfigured with the relevant type information corresponding to each subclass of ISubject that it might see. The link provided in blindmeis's answer is one way to do that.
- provide a separate service operation by which the client can translate the ID of the subclass to type metadata for the subclass (perhaps as an XSD schema from which the client could generate a suitable serializable .NET type to round trip the XML).
- it would also be feasible in principle for the service to pass type metadata in some format within the headers of the response containing the serialized object. The client would need to read, interpret and act on the type infomation in an appropriate fashion.

Whichever way, it would be a lot of effort and is not the standard way of using WCF. You will have to decide if it's worth it.

Comment: Hello Chris, I appreciate your answers so much. I like the third way you mentioned on above. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing something :)

A major concept with web services and WCF is that we can pass our objects across the network, and the client can work with the same objects as the server.  Additionally, when a client adds a service reference in Visual Studio, the server will send the client all the details it needs to know about any types which will be passed across the network.

There should be no need for reflection.

There's a lot to cover, but I suggest you start with this tutorial which covers WCF DataContracts - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFHostingAndConsuming.aspx

Comment: Thank you Greg. But in my case, type of object to be transmitted is unknow to client. The WCF service only knows the base interface - ISubject and the specific type is defined by framework user.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make sense.  How can a client receive an object it doesn't know about?  Your client should become "aware" of the objects when you add the service reference, or (if the service reference is not providing Metadata Exchange Info) you should be able to create proxy client objects based on the data being received.  You say the WCF service only knows about the base interface and that the type of object is unknown to the client - this is an impossible situation.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize an object the receiving side will need to have the assembly the type is defined in.

Perhaps you should consider some type of remoting or proxying setup where the instance of ISubject lives on one side and the other side calls back to it. This may be problematic if you need to marshal large amounts of data across the wire.

Comment: I'm totally new to WCF. Could you pelase be more specific?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with WCF either but the general sort of problem is "I have a type that can be instantiated on one machine or process and I need to use it on another". Keywords to search for are Remoting, MarshalByRefObject and Remote Procedure Calls.

Comment: -1 The first sentence is not true for WCF.  Remoting is irrelevant and will only confuse the OP.  MarshalByRefObject is well beyond the scope, as are RPCs :)

Answer (score 0):

wcf needs to know the real object(not an interface!) which should be sent across the wire. so you have to satisfy the server AND the clientproxy side from the WCF service that they know the types. if you dont know the object type while creating the WCF service, you have to find a way to do it in a dynamic way. i use the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151242/wcf-known-type-from-system-object-in-config) to get the knownTypes to my WCF service.

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required]
[ServiceKnownType("GetServiceKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypeHelper))]//<--!!!
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    object DoSomething(object obj);
}
```

if you have something "universal" like the code above, you have to be sure that whatever your object at runtime will be, your WCF service have to know this object.

you wrote your client create a subclass and sent it back to the service. if you want to do that, WCF(clientproxy and server!) needs to know the real type of your subclass.

Comment: Hi blindmeis, in my case, the concrete type (inherited from ISubject) is defined in a plug-in package and can't be a 'knowntype' at design time. Thanks for your answer.